# Pig Inner Join produces a Job with 1 hanging reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a Pig Script that I've been working on that has an Inner Join from 2 different data sources. This join happens to be the 1st MapReducing causing operation. With the only operations before hand being filters and foreachs. When this Join is then executed everything goes threw the map phase perfectly and fast, but when it comes to the reduce phase all the reducers but 1 finish fast. However the 1 just sits there at the Reduce part of the Phase chugging over data at a very very slow pace. To the point that it can take up to an hour+ just waiting on that 1 reducer to complete. I have tried increasing the reducers as well as switching to a skewed join, but nothing seems to help.

Any ideas for things to look into.

I also did an explain to see if I could see anything, but that just shows a simple single job flow with nothing amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely what is happening is a single key has huge number of instances on both sides and it's exploding.

For example, if you join:

```
x,4      x,'f'
x,5      x,'g'
x,6   X  x,'h'
y,7      x,'i'
```

... you will get 12 pairs of `x`! So you can imagine that if you have 1000 of one key and 2000 of the same key in the other data set, you will get 2 million pairs just from those 2000 rows. The single reducer unfortunately has to take the brunt force of this explosion.

Adding reducers or using a skew join isn't going to help here, because at the end of the day, a single reducer needs to handle this one big explosion of pairs.

Here are a few things to check:

1. It sounds like only a single join key is causing this issue since only one reducer is getting hammered. The common culprit is `NULL`. Can the column in either of these be NULL? If so, it'll get a huge explosion! Try filtering out `NULL` on the foreign key of both relations before running through the join and see if there is a difference. Or, instead of NULL... perhaps you have some sort of default value or a single value that shows up a lot.
2. Try to figure out how many of each key there actually are, and figure out what the explosion will look like. Something like (warning: I'm not actually testing this code, hopefully it works):

   ```
   A1 = LOAD ... -- load dataset 1
   B1 = GROUP A1 BY fkey1;
   C1 = FOREACH B1 GENERATE group, COUNT_STAR(A1) as cnt1;

   A2 = LOAD ... -- load dataset 2
   B2 = GROUP A2 BY fkey2;
   C2 = FOREACH B2 GENERATE group, COUNT_STAR(A2) as cnt2;

   D = JOIN C1 by fkey1, C2 by fkey2;  -- do the join on the counts
   E = FOREACH D GENERATE fkey1, (cnt1 * cnt2) as cnt;   -- multiply out the counts

   F = ORDER E BY cnt DESC; -- order it by the highest first
   STORE F INTO ...
   ```
3. Similarly, it may have nothing to do with an explosion. One of your relations might just have a single key a ton of times. For example, in the word count example, the reducer that ends up with the word "the" is going to have a lot more counting to do than the one that gets "zebra". I don't think this is the case here since only one of your reducers is getting hammered, which is why I think #1 is probably the case.

If you have some huge number for one of the keys, that's why. And you also know what key is causing the issue.

Comment: So there was a large number of null's but that didn't appear to be the over all case, but did lead me to the root problem. It appears a Google Bot (Google Web Preview) as screwing with ID's that where suppose to be different between a set of calls, but it appears they are doing something weird to our JS and causing the ID's to not change between thousands of calls. So when a join using this ID would happen. I'd end up a massive cross product instead of a 1 to 1 join expected.